# AWK How to extract substrings from from a variables position and different separator?

Tags: string, awk, substring, extract

My input is a file with a thouthans of lines like this:

```
|0401549244492||20210319163253|1080|0||||||{"key":150,"value":"DLO"},{"key":154,"value":"249920"}
|040148992444924||20210319163253|1080|0||||||{"key":150,"value":"DLO"},{"key":154,"value":"446910"}
```

Positions arent the same.. i need extract strings inside of `""` ex: `DLO` and `5492444924` (from keyy `150` and key `155`..) and extract strings between `|` .. its hard for me the firts.. i need make a file with these strings but without `|` either key word or `:` or `""`.. none of these

i need this, with same positions and fill with `0`.

```
0401549244492002021031916325310800DLO249920 

0401489924449242021031916325310800DLO446910
```

A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the last 2 rows is the expected output? If so, you can try this `awk` but I do not fully understand the request.

```
awk -F"[}|,\":]" '{print $2 $4 $5 $6 $15 $20}'

04015492444922021031916325310800DLO249920
0401489924449242021031916325310800DLO446910
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! i didnt know i could define many separators, i thought it was only one :).